# in C programming, how can we initialize this int *goo, where goo is a list of edges for a graph?

Tags: c, list, graph

In C programming, how can we initialize this `int *goo`, where goo is a list of edges for a graph?

Comment: `int *goo` is a (pointer to) a flat array of integers. How do you intend to store the edges of a graph in something like this?

Answer (score 2):

A one-dimensional integer array cannot in general be used to store a graph intuitively, i.e. without some sort of mapping code.

There are at least two common ways to mathematically represent a graph in a matrix/array. Assuming `N` numbered vertices and `M` edges:

- An `N x N` [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). This is a two-dimensional array, where each *vertex* has its own line.
- An `M-sized` [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list). This essentially boils down to a list of the edges and can be implemented as a `M x 2` array, where each *edge* has its own line.

Both of these representations are intuitively two-dimensional `K x L` arrays. You *can* use a one-dimensional array by using extra code to place the data in a `(K * L) x 1` one-dimensional array `A`. E.g. to get the `(i, j)` element of the original `K x L` array:

```
e = A[i * L + j];
```

Then you can simply allocate the array dynamically:

```
int *A = (int *)malloc(K * L * sizeof(int));
```

(Before anyone whines about the explicit cast, it is needed in C++ and that's a good enough reason for me)